# Why is this opamp PWM circuit not giving a PWM output?

Tags: operational-amplifier, class-d

I thought I'd see a PWM rectangular wave at opamp output, but the simulation gives a constant +Vsat.
Why am I not getting PWM ?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRGILv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

EDIT: After fixing VEE error pointed out by Transistor, still not getting the clean PWM output:(

[image]

EDIT: changing opamp to TL072 as suggested by G36 in the comments fixed the issue:

[image]

Comment: Slew rate is the answer. And try to use a Comparator instead of an opamp.

Comment: Ohk but opamp has gain till 1MHz and I'm just giving 10kHz, slew rate still affects?

Comment: It should work.

Comment: Ignore my answer. In this case the Transistor answer is correct.

Comment: ..... assuming you got the power rails correct muhuhahaha

Comment: I swear it was an human error Andyyyy. @Transistor I fixed the powersupply but still not getting the clean PWM:(

Comment: change to TL072

Comment: My textbook has https://prnt.sc/rtdf3a

Comment: @G36 that worked! Probably it has to do with the difference in slew rates as you mentioned earlier. I'm gona google a bit and see how these are different..

Comment: An LM324 isn't man enough for 10 kHz.

Comment: @Andyaka lmao you're not alone hating its guts! found [this funny discussion](https://www.electro-tech-online.com/threads/i-hate-lm324.88807/) while trying to find differences in opamps from different vendors:  `The LM324 sucks. It is the filthiest, disease-riddled piece of silicon ever to insult common sand with it's presence. I once was lured into putting one on an opto. Just an ordinary opto.`

Comment: The LM324 is, by comparison, infinitely better than the 741.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. Neatly tucked away under the V<sub>EE</sub> label is a -15 V parameter on the V2 supply.*

The - terminal of a -15 V supply is +15 V. You have powered the op-amp with two +15 V supplies.

Switch it to +15 V.

Comment: good eye:) I played with optimally positioning both supplies and messed up haha